# Android gmaps doesnt work with minifyEnabled = true... apiKey are setted

Tags: android, google-maps, proguard

I don't speak english, but...

I'm making an android app that uses GMaps v2. 
All is well in debug mode, but when I lunch the release app, the maps code doesn't execute!

I'm sure that the release apiKey is well setted (I set it in src/release/values/google_maps_api.xml and the apiKey doesn't have restriction), and because if I set minifyEnabled = false in release build type, it works!, so I think that it's a problem with proguard...

I try all combinations of the next proguard rules but nothing...

```
-keep class com.google.** {*;}

-keep class com.hawk.angela.home.activities.MapFragment { *; }


-keep class com.google.android.gms.maps.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.android.gms.maps.** { *; }

-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle { protected Object[][] getContents(); }
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-dontoptimize

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment

# The Maps API uses custom Parcelables.
# Use this rule (which is slightly broader than the standard recommended one)
# to avoid obfuscating them.
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static *** CREATOR;
}

# The Maps API uses serialization.
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
```

Moreover, the console doesn't return any exception

The map initialization is in a Fragment:

```
MapView mapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
Bundle mapState = (savedInstanceState != null) ?
        savedInstanceState.getBundle("mapState") :
        null;
mapView.onCreate(mapState);
mapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately

mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
        googleMap = mMap;
        googleMap.setMaxZoomPreference(maxZoom);

        // ...
    }
});
```

Can anyone help me please? At least where I have to find the problem...

Thanks!!

EDIT: 
AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.enzonotario.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false" />

    <!-- GCM permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!-- Pusher service -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <!-- Storage -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="DATABASE"
            android:value="app.db" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="VERSION"
            android:value="2" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="QUERY_LOG"
            android:value="false" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME"
            android:value="com.enzonotario.app" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.enzonotario.app.utils.GlideConfigurationModule"
            android:value="GlideModule" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAqRP3ZQzc9gOhs3elhs7AL0qUo6wQOwZ8" />

        <!-- Pusher's FCM listeners and services -->
        <service android:name="com.pusher.android.notifications.fcm.FCMMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.pusher.android.notifications.fcm.FCMInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".SyncService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <receiver android:name=".gps.receivers.GpsLocationReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        // so many activities
    </application>
</manifest>
```

google_maps_api.xml (release)

```
<resources>
    <!--
    TODO: Before you release your application, you need a Google Maps API key.

    To do this, you can either add your release key credentials to your existing
    key, or create a new key.

    Note that this file specifies the API key for the release build target.
    If you have previously set up a key for the debug target with the debug signing certificate,
    you will also need to set up a key for your release certificate.

    Follow the directions here:

    https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/signup

    Once you have your key (it starts with "AIza"), replace the "google_maps_key"
    string in this file.
    -->
    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">
        AIzaSyAqRP3ZQzc9gOhs3elhs7AL0qUo6wQOwZ8
    </string>
</resources>
```

Comment: have you tried using mapfragment instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was not in the gmaps, but in the materialtabs library that I had used (https://github.com/neokree/MaterialTabs), now I use https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The API key for Google Maps must be explicitly set-up in the AndroidManifest.xml for this to work.

For debug mode it can be set-up in google_maps_api.xml BUT for release build it must be in AndroidManifest.xml

E.g.

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="<your API key here>"/>
```

I usually create two keys when I do this. One for debug and one for release. This is necessary because the SHA for debug is different for release and thus you need to create two separate API keys for each.

So my AndroidManifest.xml looks somewhat like the one below. When I shift builds from debug to release or release to debug, I just uncomment the meta-data.

```
    <!-- Development/Debug Google Maps API Key -->
    <!--<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/> -->

    <!-- Release Google Maps API Key -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="<my API key here>"/>
```

Comment: @EnzoNotario did you create two API keys? one for debug and one for release? The SHA for debug must different for the SHA of release. I updated my answer, btw.

Comment: yes.. I have two apiKey... I tryed to submit the SHA for debug and release, but now I have the apiKey not restricted, anyway I already tryed with submit the SHA-1... http://imgur.com/a/ynvhE

Comment: @EnzoNotario is it okay if you edit your question ang post the code for google_maps_api.xml and AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @EnzoNotario i noticed that the API key in the google_maps_api.xml is the same as the one in AndroidManifest.xml. i thought you had two API keys? one for debug and one for release?

Comment: Yes, I have two... the apiKey in google_maps_api is the release apiKey, anyway it is not used since you said me that the apiKey must be in the AndroidManifest... before in AndroidManifest I had @string/google_maps_key and with another apiKey for google_maps_api(debug)

Comment: that is okay, i can still understand you. so the one in the AndroidManifest.xml is the release key? is that correct? Can you comment the API key from the google_maps_api.xml please. and create a new release APK and deploy.

Comment: yes... but now I realized that the other map that I have in an activity works! the other one that I have in a fragment doesn't works (only in release mode with minifyEnabled=true, in debug mode it works perfectly)... I need that it works in a fragment because I use Tabs...

Comment: that is okay. because whether it is in a different activity or fragment it will still communicate with your Google account with the API key. the set-up of the the key, i think, is the issue here. try to comment out the API key in google_maps_api.xml and just put the release key in AndroidManifest.xml. And also restrict again this release key in your Google account using the SHA1 information. and then try again.

Comment: I think that you don't understand me... I have an activity (a place picker) that has a gmaps that works, and I use the gmaps in the same way that I'm trying to use in a fragment, but in the fragment it simply does not works... all with the same configuration of the apiKey. So now, I'm sure that the problem is not in the apiKey, but in the use of gmaps in the fragment... but works in an activity! it's rare

Comment: One last comment and I will stop if it doesn't still work. Do you have this piece of code in the onCreate of your Activity - `SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);`

Comment: No, since I use MapView instead of SupportMapFragment... but now I tryed to use SupportMapFragment. In the activity it works perfectly, in the fragment not... maybe it simply will not works in an fragment, I will trying to fix it... thanks so so so much!

Comment: Hope you fix it soon. And just a suggestion, maybe you can edit the question so other developers who is familiar with the problem can help.

Comment: @EnzoNotario btw (just one last try :) ) this is the code in my layout for the fragement. `<fragment android:id="@+id/map"                      android:name="com.google.android.m4b.maps.SupportMapFragment"                      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"/>`

Comment: I have this:
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

I tryed your code, but I don't have the "m4b" package (and it seems to be premium plan? https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/android-get-started)

Comment: It is premium plan. And basically yours is also correct for the free account "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment". what happened after you edited it? Did you try to add this - `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" `

Comment: yes I tryed it, and doesn't works... It will make me crazy

Comment: sorry! but the problem seems to be in the materialtabs package (https://github.com/neokree/MaterialTabs) that I used. Because, even if I remove the MapFragment that I had put in it, it doesn't works (the tabs) I thought that the map was the problem and was the why the maps nor tabs doesn't show... so I'll try with another tab package... sorry, but I hope that it's the problem... thanks for your time!

Comment: Yes!!! that was the f.... problem!!! now I use https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout . THANKS again! and sorry.. :)

Comment: You can post another answer to your question. For other's reference :)